# MySQL is inserting NULL values

Tags: php, mysql, null

have some trouble with my table.

With every new request, MySQL add a NULL value and i dont know why :( in fact all my column data are "shifted", any idea how to fix that ? thanks

To add a query into SQL i use this kind of code :

PS : even when i set my column into NOT NULL it replace the name with blank.

```
require_once 'sql.php';
  $sqlConnexion = new mysqli($hn,$un,$pw,$db);
    if($sqlConnexion->connect_error){
      die ('Soucis de connexion SQL');}
       $date = date("d/m/y G:i:s");

 if(isset($_POST['zoneDeText'])){
 $area = $_POST['zoneDeText'];

$A = preg_replace('/\s{1,}/',' ', $area);
    $B =preg_replace('/^\s/','', $A);
            $C = preg_replace('/,$/', '', $B);
                $explode = explode(' ', $C);

if($C != ''){
$instruction= $sqlConnexion->prepare("INSERT INTO entry SET entréesUtilisateurs=?");
    if($instruction !== false){
        $instruction->bind_param('s', $C);
            $instruction->execute();
                $instruction->close();
    }else{
        echo "Trouble inserting $C";
    }
```

[SQL  trouble in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAKqB.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we prefer you to put all relevant code into your question. We don't want to go look at other, offsite links to dig through your codebase. Also - those links can go stale, but we want Stack Overflow to be forever (in case somebody else has the same problem as you)... so please edit your question, and add the relevant code/errors into your question (please don't add an image of the problem - copy/paste the actual text so we can likewise copy/paste bits to provide a solution). Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried `echo $C` to see what value it has?

Comment: try to use the standard form of INSERT so as not to freak people out. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using "INSERT INTO entry SET"?

You should use "INSERT INTO entry(entréesUtilisateurs, SortieTraitée, Date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"

Comment: Oh my god, i'm new, your code works pretty well =) just another think, let's say i want to put Date later in database and "entréesUtilisateurs & SortieTraitée" are already in, how can i add Date near them without getting a NULL shift ? thanks !

Comment: Than you should use "UPDATE" query instead of "INSERT". Try this for example "UPDATE entry set Date = ? WHERE entréesUtilisateurs = ?"

Comment: There's no practical difference between `INSERT...SET` and `INSERT...VALUES`